# Easiest sortig of list of objects with java 8 lambda

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, comparator

I have a list with objects, and I am looking for the easiest way to sort that list by java 8:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Integer someInteger;
    private String someString;
}

private List<MyClass> myClasses;
```

In this question, I have already tried out the java 8 answer:

```
Collections.sort(myClasses, (MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> m1.someInteger.compareTo(m2.someInteger));
```

But my Eclipse is yelling:

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type
Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<MyClass>,
(MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> {})
```

and:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<MyClass> to Comparator<? super T>
```

I have also found an another example:

```
myClasses.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyClasse::getSomeInteger));
```

But also with error:

```
The method sort(Comparator<? super MyClass>) in the type List<MyClass>
is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<MyClass>)
```

So how could I do it in the easiest way?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you not able to compare objects?

Comment: The easiest was is to respect the "information hiding" principle and have your Class implementing `Comparable`. The second easiest way is to access the classes properties via *getters* instead of direct use.

Comment: The first attempt `Collections.sort`. I cannot see how this is possible since `someInteger` is private and therefore cannot access it using `m1.someInteger`. Also take a look at [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/) for the exact syntax

Comment: @Timothy Truckle: since an order based on one of two properties is not *natural*, the class should not implement `Comparable`, but rather provide prebuilt `Comparator`s for the properties, e.g. as static fields, `static final Comparator<MyClass> BY_SOME_INTEGER = Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.someInteger), BY_SOME_STRING = Comparator.comparing(o -> o.someString);`…

Comment: @Holger *"since an order based on one of two properties is not natural,"* You don't  know (and neither me) what the "natural order" of this classes objects is, only victorio *may* know...

Comment: @Timothy Truckle: that’s right, that’s why the recommendation should *not* be to implement `Comparable`. A property based comparator is never wrong for sorting according to a property, but implementing `Comparable` with a logic ignoring at least one of the properties can be wrong (and usually is). You can also see it the other way round: if victorio considered this to be the natural order, his class already implemented `Comparable`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error is a bit misleading here. In this case it just tells you that your lambda expression does not compile. Specifically, for the reason that you try to access private fields from outside `MyClass`.

For example this line:

```
Collections.sort(myClasses, (MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> m1.nonExistingField);
```

will produce the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<MyClass>, (MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> {})
    Comparator<MyClass> cannot be resolved to a type
    MyClass cannot be resolved to a type
    MyClass cannot be resolved to a type

    at ap.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:11)
```

Comment: Thanks! As I see, it is also working with **Collections.sort(myClasses, (MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> m1.getSomeInteger().compareTo(m2.getSomeInteger()));** and with **Collections.sort(myClasses, (MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> m1.getSomeInteger());**. True?

Comment: Oh no, it is not yelling because it is an integer, and the compareTo also returns as an Integer. Sorry!